# rotating the view for android x86 on VMWare

Tags: vmware, android-x86, vmware-player

How to I rotate the display view on android x86 installed in <kbd>VMWare</kbd>? Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> rotated it so that the back and home buttons went to the left of the screen, but now pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> only keep it in landscape mode, with either the home button being towards the left or the right of the screen. How do I bring it back to portrait mode, that is, the home button at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd>, it will solve the problem and <kbd>f9</kbd>, <kbd>f10</kbd>, <kbd>f11</kbd>, <kbd>f12</kbd> controls the different direction.

Comment: This did not work for me, is there any other solution?

Comment: Does not solve the issues for the applications that force particular orientation :-(

Answer (score 0):

For my installation (Windows 8.1 Host, VMWare Player v7.1.0) I had to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key didn't work)

I.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd>; <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f10</kbd>; <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f11</kbd>; <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd>